# JScrollPane Contents Not Showing

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JTextArea inside of a JPanel that is then placed into the JScrollPane. When the JPanel that contains the JScrollPane is first show the JScrollPane shows up but not the contents. As soon as the JFrame is resized the contents show up.

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(6, 20);
area.setText("Some test text");

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
pane.setBounds(20, 20, WIDTH - 40, 300 - 40);
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH - 40, 300 - 40));
add(pane);
pane.setViewportView(panel);
```

Comment: It works fine for me.  Perhaps you need to show more code so we can understand your problem since I don't see the bug in the code you've posted. Perhaps show where you've added stuff to the JFrame and then make it visible. Do you call pack and setVisible(true) **after** adding the components?  Best would be to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Also, what's with the setBounds business?

Comment: I tested the code and everything seems ok

Answer (score 3):

```
pane.setBounds(20, 20, WIDTH - 40, 300 - 40); 
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH - 40, 300 - 40));
```

Those two lines of code doen't make sense (although they are not the cause of your problem)

The first line is used when you are using a "null layout".

The second is used when you are using layout managers.

They should not be used together.

The second is preferred since you should be using layout managers.

Comment: Oh thats just some leftover code that I never took out but thanks regardless.

Comment: @Glenn Nelson, When you post code the code you post should be the "exact" code you are using to we don't spend time on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Well given the code is ~600 lines long I thought it would be an idea not to. I didn't realize where the problem was and I though it was there.

Comment: We did not ask for 600 lines of code!!! You where asked for a SSCCE!!! Most times the problem is NOT where you think it is. That is why you need to isolate the problem, which is the purpose of the SSCCE.

Answer (score 2):

In the application different JPanels are swapped out in a manner similar to a slide-show. So something like this would be found in the code:

```
panel.remove(slide1);
panel.add(slide2);
panel.repaint();
```

The problem being that all of the contents of the second slide, slide2, would not show up. The solution is to add

```
frame.validate();
```

Where frame is the parent window of panel.

Comment: Or if you don't use a CardLayout, then you would use panel.revalidate() followed by, panel.repaint(). There is no need to validate the entire frame.

Answer (score 1):

`new JScrollPane(panel);`

I believe that you need to add the panel to the scroll pane constructor.